# Twig access object

Tags: php, twig

i want to access the value of a object inside a twig template.

Normally i would get the return like that:

```
echo $lang->get("test");
```

But how can i do the same in the template with twig?

I tried so many methods but no one worked.

For example i tried:

```
{{ attribute(lang, get, 'test') }}
```

with the result

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to
>   Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Twig_Node_Expression_Array, instance of Twig_Node_Expression_Constant
>   given

thanks

Comment: Did you try `lang.get('test')`?

Comment: Yep i did. Wont work aswell.

Comment: I was here looking for something else but saw your question; I don't know if much has change in the last couple of years of Twig, but for at least the last 5 months since I started using twig, this has worked fine. For example `{% for TNS in tnm.getTNservice(user_id) %}
 {{ TNS.tn_id }}
 {% for TNP in tnm.getTNpublications(TNS.tn_id) %}
     {{ TNP.publication_id }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you're trying to do is call a method on an object with parameters in a Twig template. I do not think this is supported, as it's probably viewed as a bad idea. Twig supports the notion of getters on an object though, which are called without parameters:

```
{{ lang.test }}
```

will try to invoke one of the following, in this order:

- `$lang->test`
- `$lang->test()`
- `$lang->getTest()`
- `$lang->isTest()`

If the object implements any of these accessors and conventions, Twig will find it. Anything outside of this convention, like `get('test')`, is not part of the Twig philosophy. And it's not a widely used idiom in general, so you should probably stick to one of the above methods.

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables.

You can implement `__isset`, `__get` or `__call` magic methods to support one of these accessor methods.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that doesnt help me too much. the thing is that the object i try to call is for a language system and return me the language string i want. in the example above it return the string for the variable "test". hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: You should implement this as a filter or function extension to Twig then, not an an object that takes dynamic parameters. In fact, I have done exactly that in [this fork here](https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions) (with an open pull request [here](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/pull/76)). It's a much more elegant system than passing translation objects to the view.

Comment: ALso at:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

there are attributes? :/

Comment: I guess `attribute(lang, 'get', 'test')` should do it (note the quotes around `get`). Never used this though.

Comment: To your answer with that filter:

Sry but how do i have to use that? Im relative new with twig.

To the last answer:

that throws the same error as in my first post (the question)

Comment: To implement your own filters, see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters. But really, try my above gettext extension. Download the code from [here](https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions) and see the manual here: https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/gettext.rst.

Comment: I need to download and upload the complete Package? Or just the gettext folder? If the first is right, is it the newest twig version? Thanks

Comment: It's the Twig *Extension* repository, it's not the primary Twig software. You have to download and install it *in addition to* the Twig you already have. And yes, take the package as a whole.

Comment: Okay i tried your Extension now. I use de_DE. I  have the compiled .mo in the includes\locale\de_DE\LC_ALL folder. the problem is that its still print the original string and not the translatet one.

Comment: The default category is `LC_MESSAGES`, not `LC_ALL`. Make sure the `includes/locale` directory is bound via `bindtextdomain('default', 'includes/locale');`. Then select that domain as default using `textdomain('default')`. That means the `.mo` file has to be named `includes/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo`.

Comment: If i try with LC_MESSAGES i get the following:

Notice: Use of undefined constant LC_MESSAGES - assumed 'LC_MESSAGES' 
Deprecated: setlocale(): Passing locale category name as string is deprecated. Use the LC_* -constants instead 
Warning: setlocale(): Invalid locale category name LC_MESSAGES, must be one of LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, or LC_TIME 

The other settings are right. And if i use LC_ALL it just wont get translated. With the php-gettext it worked without twig (using LC_MESSAGES). But it looks like it snot compatible with your extension. Thanks for help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23039/discussion-between-user1766080-and-deceze)

Comment: Okay i found it out. It was a problem with XAMPP Local Server. Now it works fine. Hope it does on webspace too :/. Any plans making it compatible with "php-gettext"? Thanks for your help

Comment: Good to hear. No, I have no plans on making it work with php-gettext. It should be pretty simple to adapt it though. I'd `extend` [the `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Gettext` class](https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Gettext.php) and simply map the function names to php-gettext, should be pretty simple. If you want to fork my code and do a sample implementation of that, we can maybe abstract the whole thing enough to be compatible with all sorts of gettext replacements.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty much all the Twig Gettext extension does, it's mapping certain filter and function names used in Twig templates to the PHP gettext functions, there isn't a lot to it. The biggest part of the Twig Gettext extension really is the Extractor, which gets the strings marked up as such out of the template into .pot files.

Comment: Yes it very similar to the normal gettext function. The only code writing difference is that the syntax is T_('Hier you can find stuff about me.');. So only the "T" has been added. But the big difference is that its working on every system, and the chaching problem is solved. So is it possible to add that "T"? then it should work fine

Answer (score 9):

Going back to one of your original attempts:

```
{{ attribute(lang, get, 'test') }}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing, and this should work according to the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html).  Unfortunately, there are no examples of using this.  All I found was that the method name (get) had to be a string ('get'), so I changed that, but it still didn't work.  What I ended up doing was this:

```
{% set myText = lang.get('test') %}
{{ myText }}
```

This worked great, but it's a lot of code to write when I have to do this all over.  So I made a simple template with both methods and examined the compiled output.  The original was compiled to this:

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["lang"]) ? $context["lang"] : null), "get", "test"), "html", null, true);
```

and the second (2 liner) to this:

```
$context["myText"] = $this->getAttribute((isset($context["lang"]) ? $context["lang"] : null), "get", array(0 => "test"), "method");
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, (isset($context["myText"]) ? $context["myText"] : null), "html", null, true);
```

After examination, I realized the difference (check the 3rd parameters to getAttribute), the arguments parameter is an array!  This is good information to know.  I changed my original to this:

```
{{ attribute(lang, 'get', ['test']) }}
```

and it's now working!

Comment: Amazingly, this is what the error message indicates (Array expected, got constant)