# making a Tree with Entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm beginning with symfony and I want build the architecture of my website like a tree and call some methods recursively to render with Twig. 
But I have an error and it display this: "ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: text in D:\Documents\site_cdm\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php line 269"

This error is trigged when i want know if the chidren item have children.

```
{% if root.children is not empty %}
    {% for item in root.children %}
        {% if item.children is not empty %}<-- the error is trigged here!
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ path('cdm_site_article_id', { 'id': item.id }) }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.name }}</a>
            {{ include('cdmSiteBundle:Component:menu.html.twig', {'root': item, 'cssClass':"dropdown-menu"}) }} </li>
        {% else %}
           <li><a href="{{ path('cdm_site_article_name', { 'name': item.name }) }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I can't also get the item.id but the item.name yes.

Can you help me please :)

My vision of the architecture:
http://imageshack.com/a/img836/7014/e55d.png

the reverse engineering of my database:
http://imageshack.com/a/img834/4026/ktp3.png

The buildMenuAction in Controller:

```
class ComponentController extends Controller
{
  public function buildMenuAction()
  {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('cdmSiteBundle:Category');

    $root = $repository->findOneByName('root');
    echo $root->getId();
    return $this->render('cdmSiteBundle:Component:menu.html.twig', array(
        'root'=>$root,
        'cssClass'=>"nav navbar-nav"
    ));
}
```

The Entity Module:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as Orm;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**   
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"category" = "Category", "article" = "Article", "item" = "Item"})
 */
class Module {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Module", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Module", mappedBy="parent")
 **/
private $children;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

The Entity Article:

```
    namespace cdm\SiteBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    use cdm\SiteBundle\Entity\Module;

/**
 * Article
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="cdm\SiteBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
*/
class Article extends Module
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="createDate", type="date")
 */
private $createDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastUpdateDate", type="date")
 */
private $lastUpdateDate;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $content;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->createDate = new \Datetime(); // Par défaut, la date de l'article est la date d'aujourd'hui
    $this->lastUpdateDate = new \Datetime();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your action for passing `root`? Do you have method called `getChildren()` in your entity?

Comment: the post is edited and yes i have a getChildren()

Comment: I provided an answer check it hopefully helps you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct property name, use the getter for children and other properties in your twig file

```
{% if root.getChildren.count > 0 %}
  {% for item in root.getChildren %}
    {% if item.getChildren.count() > 0 %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ path('cdm_site_article_id', { 'id': item.getId }) }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ item.getName }}</a>
        {{ include('cdmSiteBundle:Component:menu.html.twig', {'root': item, 'cssClass':"dropdown-menu"}) }} </li>
    {% else %}
       <li><a href="{{ path('cdm_site_article_name', { 'name': item.getName }) }}">{{ item.getName }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the result is same. I saw this post before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413550/twig-access-object

Comment: Yes you are right; the issue must be in your entity. I think you may not need to define `$children` in your entity; you can create a function `getChildren()` in your entity which runs a query to select the children and return them, instead.

Comment: but this will brake my ORM map. it shall work because it exactly the same of the example into the doctrine doc -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html (chapter 5.12. One-To-Many, Self-referencing)

Comment: Base on the documentation the only different I see is `strategy="IDENTITY"` which should be `strategy="AUTO"` in Module entity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in buildMenuAction :

```
public function buildMenuAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('cdmSiteBundle:Module');

    $root = $repository->findOneByName('root');

    return $this->render('cdmSiteBundle:Component:menu.html.twig', array(
        'root'=>$root,
        'cssClass'=>"nav navbar-nav"
    ));
}
```

I have to get the base class if i want get articles and categories. Before i wrote this: ->getRepository('cdmSiteBundle:Category').

Now I need to include an interface and limit my tree to display only article and category.